# writing to a file in python skipping some rows

Tags: python

I have a input file(TSV) with 500k rows. I am cooking the data and writing the data to the output file as follows:

```
fd = pd.read_csv('/home/ubuntu/Downloads/netdriver_1.txt', sep="\t",header=None, names = ["hex"])
a = fd.hex.str[8:57]
f = open('myfile', 'w')
f.write(str(a))  # python will convert \n to os.linesep
f.close()
```

Only the few rows in the beginning and few rows rows at the end is showing with ... in inbetween as follows:

```
row1
row2
row3
....
row507050
row507051
```

I need all the rows in the output file.

Comment: Didnt completley got you - you want the ... to be lines? (\n)?

Comment: Why are you not using something like [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)? It looks like you're just making a string representation of the DataFrame?

Comment: I would use the `csv` module vs pandas given the size. Iterate over the `csv.reader` and write each cell as encountered.

Comment: By default, `pandas` `str()` displays only the first and the last 30 rows and it replaces all other rows with a `...`.